# Atom Editor JSX formatting looks terrible, how to fix?

Tags: reactjs, atom-editor

I have a simple .js with some embedded jsx which when saving gets formatted like so:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return ( < h1 > It Works! < /h1>);
      }
    }
```

clearly this is not nice and I would prefer it to look something like this:

```
class Layout extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return ( 
              <h1>It Works!</h1>
             );
             }
}
```

> Question: So how do I get it to format like this?

Comment: lol - someone was quick marking that down! two seconds!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can archieve this by installing an extension.

Go to File -> Settings -> Install
And search jsx. Find your favorite one and install it.
I'm using the following one: https://atom.io/packages/language-javascript-jsx

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue, but somehow the language-javascript-jsx package seems not be formatting my jsx as well (all tags flattened at the first indentation point).  I found the following package on the [Atom forums](https://discuss.atom.io/t/having-trouble-with-indentation-on-jsx/51234/3) which works perfectly, highlighting the matching closing tags etc, it even formats the graphql statements (besides a slew of other languages) so definitely worth a try IMHO.  Moving jsx up and down whilst holding the Ctrl key was my number one feature and it just works.

https://atom.io/packages/language-babel

With well over 1 million downloads, this seems to be the preferred package as well..

Makes my coding a lot happier :-)